# Python flask add to JSON

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm trying to create a speedrunning web site in python3 with flask. I want to have teams. I save the teams in a .json file. But I can't figure out how to add more teams. first, save the file in a var called team then I create a new var called team_cr and save the new team there. then I try to combine the two var. But it doesn't work

The JSON file with the teams:

```
[
{
    "name": "Level8",
    "members": 0,
    "publicID": "",
    "teamColor": "red",
    "games": 0,
    "win": 0,
    "kd": 0
},
{
    "name": "test",
    "members": 0,
    "publicID": "",
    "teamColor": "red",
    "games": 0,
    "win": 0,
    "kd": 0
}
]
```

The Python server-side script:

```
@app.route("/team/create", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def team_cr():

    if request.method == "GET": 
         return render_template("team_create.html") #If it is a GET request send team_create.html

    elif request.method == "POST":

        create_team(request.form["name"], request.form["color"]) # Calls the function create_team.

        return render_template("team_suc.html")   #If it is a POST request send team_succses.html


def create_team(name, color):
    with open(path+"/Teams_Public.json") as f:
        team = json.load(f) #Loads the team date to a var.

    with open('Teams_Public.json', 'w') as outfile:
        team_cr = {
                    "name": name, # Adds the name of the team to a JSON
                    "members": 0,
                    "publicID": "",
                    "teamColor": color, # Adds the color of the team to a JSON
                    "games": 0,
                    "win": 0,
                    "kd": 0
        },team #adds the old teams to the new team

        json.dump(team_cr, outfile) #write the json file to disk
```

Comment: I removed the path+"/Team_Public.json" and replace it with "Team_Public.json"

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code is creating a tuple when it looks like what you are trying to do is append the team to the your list that was loaded from the json.

```
    team_cr = {
                "name": name, # Adds the name of the team to a JSON
                "members": 0,
                "publicID": "",
                "teamColor": color, # Adds the color of the team to a JSON
                "games": 0,
                "win": 0,
                "kd": 0
    },team
```

You could try just append the new bit of data to the list.

```
team.append({your new data})
```